# how to upload image to ftp swift Xcode

Tags: swift, file-upload, ftp, image-uploading, alamofire

I create to one web project. one part in my project is for upload file/image to `FTP` server (`with username & password for connect to server`). now I want to your help for this problem. I using to `alamofire` framework for my project.

I want how to upload image to FTP server with (username & password) with `alamofire` framework

Answer (score 0):

just take a look on the guides for "Uploading":
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

just regular POST request.

Comment: my friend how to send username & password with Uploading method in Alamofire? this method haven't parameters!!!

Comment: usually you should login user to your app before doing such actions.
On other hand, this  method is also a POST method, so you can add parameters as well, try as ( haven't tested this, because I usually get users authenticated before uploading):

Alamofire.upload(.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, file: fileURL)

where parameters are your credentials